# How to get all redis keys close to expire

Tags: redis

I want to make the key live longer if some condition met.

What I think is if I can query all the keys close to expire (like 10 minutes to expire), then I can do the query-check-activate intervally.
I seached but not found any clue, if you know how to achieve it, please tell me.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying for keys based on their expiration time is not supported by Redis at the moment.

You can work around this by not using Redis' built-in expiration and managing it yourself, e.g. by using a Sorted Set to track expiration times and implementing passive and active expiration in your application.

Alternatively, you can use [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) to crawl the keyspace, fetching TTLs and performing your evaluations.